# loading dictionaries at startup with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 Dictionaries (10 entries in Dict1, 30 in Dict2). Right now I'm using this code to load them:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap l0 = new Bitmap(@"C:\0money\0.bmp", true);
    // +100 more
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    lookup.Add("0", l0);
    // +100 more
}
```

I'm planning on creating 3 more dictionaries, so total entry count will be up to 100+!

**How do I load all these dictionaries at program Startup, rather that loading (repeatedly) on button_click event?**

Edit: As many of you have suggested - I tried putting code on Form_Load event and as the result I'm getting "The name 'lookup' does not exist in the current context" error. I can't execute code on button_click event.

Comment: What's the problem in using your Form_Load event or Main method? Delay?

Comment: is this a windows app or web app?

Comment: I noticed that @AlG added the `asp.net` tag.  The OP has given no indication of that.  It could just as well be a WinForms app.

Comment: WinForms it is, I create a project in VS2010 "Windows Forms Application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **WinForms**, put your code into the form load event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>() {
        {"0", new Bitmap(@"C:\0money\0.bmp", true)},
        {"1", new Bitmap(@"C:\0money\1.bmp", true)}
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use your Dictionary in your `button_click` event, you have to keep it on the class instance or define it static as [Davy8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9701148/333404) already mentioned.

```
public class MyFancyForm {

    private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        // init dictionary
        lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>() {
            {"0", new Bitmap(@"C:\0money\0.bmp", true)},
            {"1", new Bitmap(@"C:\0money\1.bmp", true)}
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // do something with lookup
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Given that every click is a postback, every click is also a form load. This will still cause a load on every click. The OP wants to know how to make it happen _once_.

Comment: +1 - rolled back - only just realised that the question didn't explicitly say asp.net at the point at which you answered it - the tag was added later. I guess you were assuming it was WinForms. In any case - this approach won't work for asp.net but would for WinForms.

Comment: @RobLevine ah ok, i think i misunderstood the OP's problem

Comment: @RobLevine yes i thought it was a WinForms application ;)

Comment: @Alex - I've added the WinForms tag to clear up any ambiguity.

Comment: @Robar can you check out my "Edit"?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to store it in Application context (if it's going to be reused by whole app and it's not user specific).

The best way would be to do it on Application Start, which you can handle in Global.asax.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
I don't think that actually storing whole Bitmap objects is a good idea ! You might want to think again about the architecture of your app and what you are trying to achieve.

**WEB FARM SCENARIO**
In webfarm scenario, that is going to be a different scenario. Each of your apps will have a different instance of Application variables.

I'm then tempted to suggest having a session state server and keeping that in session (which will then be shared accross all apps) - you might run into some issues with standard session state server though

You might also cosider copying resources (shared by apps) on to the network path or storing as binary in database and then loading them on each server node application start - you would still have an instance of these in each server node

Comment: it won't work if the application will be deployed on a server farm because Application variables are inProc

Comment: yes, that changes everything. have a look at this article. someone has actually asked about that http://forums.asp.net/t/1113173.aspx/1

Comment: The ASP.NET tag was mistakenly added, the OP is actually using WinForms

Answer (score 2):

You can either keep it on the class instance or static, depending on how it's used.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Bitmap> _lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
static MyClass()
{
    lookup.Add("0", l0);
    // +100 more
}
```

If the instance of the class is only created once then make it non-static.  Here I'm assuming the `class` this is in is called `MyClass` change as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could `Cache` them to be shared between the users. Bear in mind that if you will deploy on a server farm you have to use a "component" to manage the cache across the web farm.

I won't use the Application context for the resons below:

*Application state is not shared among multiple servers serving the same application, as in a Web farm, or among multiple worker processes serving the same application on the same server, as in a Web garden. Your application therefore cannot rely on application state containing the same data for application state across different servers or processes. If your application will run in multi-processor or multi-server environments, consider using a more scalable option, such as a database, for data that must preserve fidelity across the application.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx

Comment: You're answering a different question - the question is not the best way to load many items into a dictionary, but how to load it up once at startup rather than on every click.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list of files are named from `0.bmp` to `100.bmp` you can do something like:

```
string startupFolder = @"C:\0money\";
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> lookup = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Bitmap l = new Bitmap(startupFolder + i + ".bmp", true); 
    lookup.Add(i.ToString(), l);
}
```

You might want to put this code in the `form_load` in order to add them in the start up.